# Kotlin: Storing and calling suspend function throws StackOverflow exception

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to implement "Try again" functionality, which means, when some request failed, user will be able to tap on "Try Again" button to resend the same request again.

In short, I have BaseViewModel with

```
lateinit var pendingMethod: suspend () -> Unit
```

and

```
fun runAsync(tryFunction: suspend () -> Unit) {
        viewModelScope.launch(errorHandler) {
            try {
                tryFunction()
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                pendingMethod = tryFunction
            }
        }
    }
```

And from view, when "Try Again" button is clicked, I call

```
viewModel.runAsync { viewModel.pendingMethod() }
```

First tap works well, but when I tap second time, it throws

`StackOverflow error: stack size 8MB`

and bunch of `invokeSuspend(..)` in the logs, which looks like there are suspend functions call each other infinitely.

Any thoughts about this?

**Update**:

I have fixed this by storing suspend function in extra variable like this

```
val temp = viewModel.pendingMethod
viewModel.runAsync { temp() }
```

Instead of

```
viewModel.runAsync { viewModel.pendingMethod() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be traced by following points

1. `pendingMethod` property is not initialized
2. `tryFunction()` call throws kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException
3. `Exception` is caught and `pendingMethod = tryFunction()` which effectivelly means `pendingMethod = pendingMethod()`  // ***this is recursive call***

next time when you call `runAsync` it essentially calls `pendingMethod()` but this time its initialized, and since `pendingMethod` does nothing but call itself, you get the stack overflow error

### So how to implement the try again functionality

Lets say you have a suspending function which executes the given request, it can be network call(`Retrofit` supports suspend keyword) or it can be database access (`Room` also supports suspend keyword). so your function looks something like

```
suspend fun executeRequest(request: RequestModel): Result
```

Now update your ViewModel as

```
// declare a live data property to notfify user that request has failed
val requestFailed: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(false)

// update runAsync
fun runAsync(request: RequestModel) = viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        executeRequest(request)
    } 
    catch (ex: Exception) {
        requestFailed.postValue(true)
    }
}
```

And in your `Activity`, `Fragment` observe the `LiveData` object to display the error to user

```
viewModel.requestFailed.observe(this, Observer{
    if(it) { 
         // Show error toast
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but unfortunately your answer doesn't suit to my question. I don't have any of that 3 possible problems, you can see code snippet in my question, and also I'm getting stackOverFlow error not anything else. About having liveData, I would not suggest do that, cause then you need to manage that liveData value and make it "false" when try again was successful, so you should implement complex logic there which is easy to escape from.

Comment: Try to debug your code and you will see that your code fails because of those three problems